# jQuery, slideToggle - add Cookies to remember the state

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How to add Cookies into this code to remember the state after refresh?

jQuery:

```
$("li.FOLDER A").click( function() {
    $(this).parent().find("UL:first").slideToggle("fast");
    if( $(this).parent().attr('className') == "FOLDER" ) return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li class="FOLDER"><a href="#"> open folder </a>
  <ul>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="FOLDER"><a href="#"> open folder </a>
  <ul>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just hide the element based on your cookie variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use local storage instead (which is not transmitted to the server)

```
localStorage.setItem('isOpen', true);

var isOpen = localStorage.getItem('isOpen');
```

but i dont understand very well how your function works.
maybe something like this...

```
$("li.FOLDER A").click( function() {
    var isOpen = localStorage.getItem('isOpen');
    if(isOpen){
        $(this).parent().find("UL:first").slideUp("fast", function(){
            localStorage.setItem('isOpen', false);
        });

    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().find("UL:first").slideDown("fast", function(){
            localStorage.setItem('isOpen', true);
        });

    }
    if( $(this).parent().attr('className') == "FOLDER" ) return false;
})
.trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin : https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

You may want to use `$.slideDown()` and `$.slideUp()` so you can differentiate whether you are opening or closing the element

When you open the drawer:

```
$.cookie('drawer_state', 'open');
```

and when you close the drawer:

```
$.cookie('drawer_state', 'close');
```

then read the drawer state when your document loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.cookie('drawer_state') == "open"){
        $("#drawer").slideUp();
    }else{
        $("#drawer").slideDown();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li class="FOLDER"><a href="#"> open folder </a>
  <ul id="drawer">
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```